# Xamarin main method or equivalent

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm looking for an entry point like a `main()` method. Also, I have a data storage (i.e. model) class, which constantly receives data from a web socket and shall be accessible from throughout the application (i.e. from multiple ViewModels). Where can I put significant and central classes like these? Would you put these in a static class?

Also: Is there something like a `main-loop` which is responsible for handling tasks and events?

I'd be very grateful for a generic/primer overview of all the "entry points" within a Xamarin application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you for example create a Cross Platform Mobile App in Visual Studio 2017 you will already get a scaffold.  The data layer is located in the 'Services' Folder.

I would consider the "App.xaml" file as your entry point.

```
   public partial class App : Application
{
    //TODO: Replace with *.azurewebsites.net url after deploying backend to Azure
    public static string AzureBackendUrl = "http://localhost:5000";
    public static bool UseMockDataStore = false;
    public static bool UseEntityFramework = true;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (UseMockDataStore)
            DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        else if (UseEntityFramework)
            DependencyService.Register<SqLiteDataStore>();
        else
            DependencyService.Register<AzureDataStore>();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already thought about putting stuff in the `App.xaml` file. I found it a little "hidden", tho. I read about the `partial class` aspect of being helpful. I can I make use of that?

Comment: The "App.xaml" file is located on the root of your project, so you can easily find it.     "Partial" means it completes the already existing App class in the **UWP** project.   You could even create your own "public partial class App" in a separate file, but that would needlessly complicate it.    I would first try to set up your datasource in the "Services" folder.

Answer (score 5):

Each platform has their own `main()` like methods

- **Android**: `MainActivity.OnCreate()`
- **iOS**: `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)`
- **UWP**: `App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)`

on Xamarin.Forms applications all those platforms instantiates `App` class and sets the `MainPage`.

You should use `App.OnStart()` method if you want to do for BL.

Comment: Thank you very much, but, BL?

Comment: its Business Layer

Comment: It caught me out the App class in the UWP namespace (and project) is different to the App class in the shared Forms namespace (and project). I had equated the two in my mind and was getting very confused as to which was created first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about `Xamarin.Forms`,

> I'm new to Xamarin and I'm looking for an entry point like a main() method.

- Now how `Xamarin.Forms` basically works is that the respective Native Classes i.e. `MainActivity`(Android), `AppDelegate`(iOS) and the `App`(UWP) call the `App.Xaml` class in the `.Net Standard` or `PCL` project.
  So that could be considered as an entry point just like your `main()` method of a console app.

> I have a data storage (i.e. model) class, which constantly receives data from a web socket and shall be accessible from throughout the application (i.e. from multiple ViewModels).

- For this, the best way of handling it is an [SQLite Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) I would suggest you also check [this](https://medium.com/@patibrijesh/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2c6ec5894510) for a better understanding of how it works

> Where can I put significant and central classes like these? Would you put these in a static class?

- You can make them static but I would personally advise you to only put the redundant code as static. And Yes feel free to make static helper classes.

> Also: Is there something like a main-loop which is responsible for handling tasks and events?

- This part of your question is not clear to me kindly elaborate a little more

Feel free to revert in case of queries.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can override the default **MainActivity** like below:

[image]